# Build a histogram from stochastic data

Tags: plotting, data, histograms, stochastic-calculus

I have the following code yielding my stochastic "paths":

```
a = .3;
μ = .1;
c = .2;
σ = 0.1;
n = 500;
sol2 = RandomFunction[
   ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]s[t] == -a s[t] i[
        t] \[DifferentialD]t, \[DifferentialD]i[
        t] == (a s[t] i[t] - μ i[t] + 
          c (1 - s[t] - i[t]) i[t]) \[DifferentialD]t + σ i[
         t] \[DifferentialD]W[t]}, {s[t], i[t]}, {{s, i}, {0.3, 0.7}},
     t, W \[Distributed] WienerProcess[0, 1]], {0, 30, 0.01}, n];
```

I would like to make two histograms, one related to the variable s[t] and one another related to  i[t] (or better, get directly the PDF for the both variables of the process), and then approximate a gaussian curve to this histogram. I've tried a lot and had not success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've edited the post, I hope it's clearer now @HenrikSchumacher.

Comment: Maybe `Histogram[Transpose[sol2["Values"]]]` helps?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, Yes! Would you mind to make a complete asnwer? I would like to accept this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When requiring details information for many built in "data types" that are represented graphically by a gray box (e.g., `TemporalData` or `SparseArray`), it often helps to inspect their list of properties:

```
sol2["Properties"]
```

> {"Components", "DateList", "DatePath", "DatePaths", "Dates", 
>   "FirstDates", "FirstTimes", "FirstValues", "LastDates", "LastTimes", 
>   "LastValues", "Part", "Path", "PathCount", "PathFunction", 
>   "PathFunctions", "PathLength", "PathLengths", "Paths", "PathTimes", 
>   "SliceData", "SliceDistribution", "TimeList", "Times", 
>   "ValueDimensions", "ValueList", "Values"}

The properties "Values" seems promising:

```
sol2["Values"] // Dimensions
```

> {3001, 2}

So by transposing it, we can make histograms for each of its coordinates:

```
Histogram[
 Thread[
  Legended[
   Transpose[sol2["Values"]],
   {"s", "i"}
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

But I am not exactly sure whether this is what you are looking for. In the end, `sol2` represents 500 random paths in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with 3001 data points each. But it might give you an idea how to inspect `sol2` further.

Comment: @HendrikSchumacher, What's presented in the y axis is the absolute frequency? What's in the axis?

Comment: Each of the two lists in `Transpose[sol2["Values"]]` contains only values between `0.` and `0.83` or so. These are on the x-axis. I am not sure anymore whether this answers your question. Probably `sol2["DatePaths"]` is more interesting to you than `sol2["Values"]`.